# 4ma-20ma loop from 0.97V to 2.75V

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, current-measurement, loop-gain

I'm trying to develop a 4ma-20ma loop from an 0.97(4ma)-2.75(20ma) input.

This input comes from the output of a low pass filter of a PWM module.
I've searched the web quite thoroughly but all the circuits I come across are the typical 1V-5V with the 250 ohm resistance after the r2r op amp.

Is there any way I can implement this without using a gain stage before?

As I can't implement this with a fixed resistor as I need my resistor to somehow change from 242-137 ohm.

UPDATE1:So i figured out how to scale down the output to 0.5-2.3 this way I can use a gain stage to atleast get a 1V-4.6V Output but this way my max will be at 18ma instead of 20.Any suggestions?

Comment: 5x0.97 is 4.85 so this is a non-ideal input range, and gain does not fix it.

Comment: Do you have any programmable options in the receiver, so you can fix it with software scaling?

Comment: @relayman357 I can change the PWM output.It is limited to 0V-3V3 (PIC32) but I need the 0.97-2.75 as this is the range where my sensor is active (im reading from ADC input).I don't know how I could scale this to something usable

Comment: You need to look at the receiving end of the 4-20 ma. If you have control of that you may have some flexibility.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany gain need not be with respect to ground

Answer (score 1):

this will get you failry close.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHEiHQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

but this is will be less effected by temperature variations

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8pJYh.png)</sup>

Comment: I Tested the second one in LTSpice with a circuit that sims a pwm as the input(behavioral source with pulses from 0 to 2.75 with a filter after) but for some reason it only gets to 2.75V when I sim the pulses to go up to 4V.Do you know why that might be?Othewise this seems to work 100%.Thanks

Comment: it could be due to the 22K input resistance of the second circuit. but I'm sure that I understand what you designed.

Comment: perhaps a buffer amplifier before the terminal I have called "input" will help. - that's just another op-amp with -inoput connected to outout)

Comment: The buffer solved it!My LP Filter had a 10k Resistor so it was producing quite the voltage drop with the input resistance.Using the OP07 from Spice I get a 19.5mA output at max and 4.6ma at min.Still not perfect but I'll try to change the Amplifier and see if it changes it up thanks for you help Jasen!

Comment: Could someone explain the theory behind this circuit?I know this is based in a differential op amp as a current source but I can't seem to grasp how it works

Answer (score 0):

This simple current sink will give you 4-20mA for 0.55 to 2.75V. Since you're only using the 0.97 to 2.75V you lose the bottom 20% of the range if you don't scale the PWM within the PIC to the 0.55 to 2.75V range. Typical accuracy is in the 0.1% range, depending mostly on the accuracy of R1. Output impedance is close to infinite within the compliance range of about +4 to +24V, so RL of up to about 1K with a 24V supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQYtzH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>